# Ensure that bytes are written physically to serial port

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, .net-4.5

I have a serial device that uses this communication protocol:

1. turn on DTR
2. write request (4 bytes)
3. turn DTR off
4. read response (4 bytes)

`DTR` pin used to switch device mode.

I've tried to write:

```
serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
serialPort.Write(request, 0, 4);
serialPort.DtrEnable = false;
serialPort.Read(response, 0, 4);
```

But it doesn't work as expected. I get `DTR` on, then instantly `DTR` off, then 4 bytes transmission (I've used oscilloscope to determine this). I've tried to call `BaseStream.Flush()` after `Write()` call with no success. Also, simple while loop `while(serialPort.BytesToWrite > 0) Thread.Sleep(1);` gives same negative result. Serial port speed is very slow, only 600 b/s. If I add `Thread.Sleep` call after `Write` - everything ok, but I think it's very ugly and I need to switch DTR **immediately** after writing.

So, how can I determine in .NET program, when serial port buffer was physically transmitted to the device?

Comment: At 600 bits/sec, 4 bytes (probably 40 bits by the time you add stop bits, etc.) is going to take 0.0666 seconds, or 66.67 ms. Call it 70 ms. So I suspect you'll need to put a `Sleep(70)` in there if you want to be sure that the data is transmitted before you disable DTR.

Comment: I always thought DTR should be paired with DSR and both are static throughout the session **but** in order to send you set RTS and wait for a CTS after which to transmit? Thus RTS and CTS change states throughout the session

Comment: You can't get this reliable, the driver will only tell you when the transmit buffer is empty.  But modern UARTs have an on-chip FIFO buffer, usually 16 bytes deep.  You'd need a custom driver to tell you that this buffer is empty.  Realistically, this is a job for a micro-controller.  Do keep in mind that device vendors tend to come up with these kind of wonky protocols to promote their own hardware, you'll save yourself a lot of grief by buying it.  Failing any options, invest your time in making the delay more reliable, Thread.Sleep() is only accurate to 15.625 msec increments by default.

Comment: After googling for a while, I found that I can use RTS_CONTROL_TOGGLE flag and use RTS pin instead of DTR. Found [forum thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/45a89532-b01c-4ef8-aa46-532882cec004/serialport-class-and-rtscontroltoggle) on msdn. I hope this will solve my problems..